# Javascript within AppleScript 'cannot make script into type specifier' (for clicking button in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, applescript

I am trying to get the apple script to click on the radio button. I am very new to this. I am getting this error: error "Google Chrome got an error: Can’t make theScript of active tab of tab id 1.521810707E+9 of window id 1.52181061E+9 into type specifier." number -1700 from theScript of active tab of tab id 1.521810707E+9 of window id 1.52181061E+9 to specifier

The code:

```
to clickID(theID)

tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell window 1 to tell (make new tab)
        set its URL to "https://www.colonialfirststate.com.au/FirstNet/FNA/Controls/AdviserHosting.aspx?Page=BusinessReporting"
        delay 5
        set theScript to "document.getElementById('" & theID & "')'.click();"
        execute javascript theScript in active tab
    end tell
end tell
```

end clickID
clickID("optFormatCSV")

Here is a screenshot of the button and copy from inspecting the element:

[image: The Screenshot]

**InspectElement**

[image: InspectElement]

Pls help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of errors with your script:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell window 1 to tell (make new tab)
        set its URL to "https://www.colonialfirststate.com.au/FirstNet/FNA/Controls/AdviserHosting.aspx?Page=BusinessReporting"
        delay 5
        set theScript to "document.getElementById('" & theID & "')'.click();"
        execute javascript theScript in active tab
    end tell
end tell
```

You've got a stray quote before `".click()"`, which makes the JavaScript invalid; and you are targeting the `active tab` inside a `tell (make new tab)` block.  It's the latter that is producing your error:

`Can’t make theScript of active tab of tab id ... of window id ...`

There's no such object as `active tab` belonging to the `tab id ...` (the tab you just created) of `window 1`.

Simply remove the reference to the `active tab` and your code should work.  Here's what your corrected handler should look like:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell window 1 to tell (make new tab)
        set its URL to "https://www.colonialfirststate.com.au/FirstNet/FNA/Controls/AdviserHosting.aspx?Page=BusinessReporting"
        delay 5
        set theScript to "document.getElementById('" & theID & "').click();"
        execute javascript theScript
    end tell
end tell
```

---

<sup>**System info:** *AppleScript version:* `2.7`  *System version:* `10.13.6` *Chrome version:* `69`</sup>

Comment: Now I get the missing value error. Copy and paste from the "Events": "tell application "Google Chrome"
 make new tab
 set URL of tab id 1.521811198E+9 of window id 1.52181117E+9 to "https://www.colonialfirststate.com.au/FirstNet/FNA/Controls/AdviserHosting.aspx?Page=BusinessReporting"
 execute tab id 1.521811198E+9 of window id 1.52181117E+9 javascript "document.getElementById('optFormatCSV').click();"
end tell
Result:
missing value

Comment: That's not an error per se, at least, not an AppleScript error.  Your AppleScript code has processed and run correctly.  However, the `missing value` indicates that your JavaScript code didn't return a value, so there's something amiss with that.  Double check you have the correct `id`.  Try running the JavaScript code in the web inspector first to make sure it works.